# SQL Server formating time returns null values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my table I have two fields with `time(2)` type: `startTime` and `endTime`.

```
SELECT startTime, endTime FROM ...
```

gives me time formated like this: `13:00:00`. I want to display time in my app without seconds, for example `13:00`. I tried: `SELECT FORMAT(startTime, 'hh:mm') as startTime FROM ...` but when I executed it I got null values:

```
startTime
_____________
NULL
NULL
```

It's weird because If I select my data normally, like this `SELECT startTime FROM ...` I get:

```
startTime
___________
12:00:00
13:00:00
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found dirty solution: SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(startTime, 'hh'), ':', FORMAT(startTime, 'mm')) FROM ... - it works but there must be better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the colon `:` as `\:`. For example:

```
SELECT FORMAT(startTime, 'hh\:mm') as startTime FROM t
```

Result:

```
startTime
---------
12:00
13:00
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17974e2ffedb60562f3de2d25c1a5679).

Comment: Huh... TIL.   I had no idea you'd have to escape the colon on TIME but not DATETIME.   Seems rather inconsistent.  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti That is because `time` is [formatted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) as .NET's `TimeSpan`, and those [do not have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) `:` as a recognized template character. Data types that are formatted as .NET's `DateTime` do.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than format() which has terrible performance, consider `convert(...)`
or even the implicit conversion.

**Example**

```
Declare @t time = '12:00'

Select UsingConvert  = convert(varchar(5),@t,108)
      ,UsingImplicit = left(@t,5)
```

**Results**

```
UsingConvert    UsingImplicit
12:00           12:00
```